# How could I Use Python to Identify Factors Contributing to Increases and Decreases of Trends (Similar to Power BI's Insights Feature)

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, analytics, powerbi

One of Power BI's best features is the ability to identify the factors that most contribute to increases and decreases of trends. As I understand it, Machine Learning approaches are used to produce the results. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-insights

What is the best way to use Python to identify factors that most contribute to increases and decreases of trends within a dataset?

Answer (score 1):

there could be many possible answers to your question, as you can use linear and non-linear approaches to explore dependencies between change in the independent variables and the target variable.
One of the easiest approaches with high explanatory power is the function .feature_importances_ from the python package scikit-learn based on the decision tree classifier.
Once you have independent variable X and target y, syntaxis is very simple:

```
    forest = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=250,
                                  random_state=0)

    forest.fit(X, y)
    importances = forest.feature_importances_
```

You can look into more details at
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html